# android and sending files to HTTP server

Tags: android, httpserver

I try to write application which will be send file to HTTP server. Here is my android-side code:

```
public void send(View view)
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = "/data/file.txt";
    String urlServer = "http://localhost/zad1.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        Log.i("ODPOWIEDZ", serverResponseMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.i("WYJATEK", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

and here is my php script

```
<?php
    $target_path  = "./";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } 
    else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

My problem is that when I try to send file to server I get "localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused" exception. Do someone of you know what I doing wrong? Thanks for every help and tip.

Comment: Did you specify the correct URL and port?

Comment: URL "http://localhost/zad1.php" is good but I dont specify any port. Where should I do that?

Comment: OK, I solved it, I need to change "localhost" to my IP adress.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;